# How do I restore the icons of the Dock's Applications folder?

Tags: mac, finder, macos, dock

For some reason, many of the applications' icons in the Dock's Applications folder were replaced by the default application icon. I've tried [to clear the icon cache](https://gist.github.com/fabiofl/5873100), but that didn't work. Below is a screenshot of the problem.

How do I restore those icons? And for that matter, why did this happen in the first place?

I'm running MacOS Sierra on a MacBook Pro Mid 2014.

[image: The case of the disappearing icons]

Answer (score 1):

Well, I restarted and did a first aid on the volume, and now it's working. I don't know what did it, the restart or the first aid, but it's working now.